# Getting wrong data while using container_of macro

Tags: c, linux, driver

Currently i'm facing a problem with the container_of macro. In my skull_open method i want to retrieve the struct sdev, which i have initialised in the init method. But when i try to access the members in this struct (in the open method) i'll get some undefined values. So what i thought is that i probably didn't understand the container_of macro or there might be another issue which i can't see right now.

```
struct scull_dev{
        struct cdev* cdev;
        int quantum;
        int qset;
        struct scull_qset* qset_entry;
};
```

```
struct scull_qset{
    void** data;
    struct scull_qset* next;
};
```

```
static int __init init_function(void){
    int err;
    struct cdev* kernel_object;
    struct scull_dev* sdev;
    if(scull_major){
        dev = MKDEV(scull_major,scull_minor);
        err = register_chrdev_region(dev,NUMBER_DEVICES,DEVICE_NAME);
    }
    else{
        err = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev,0,NUMBER_DEVICES,DEVICE_NAME);   
    }
    if(err){
       printk(KERN_WARNING "chrdev region couldn't be allocated!\n");
       return err;  
    }
    kernel_object = cdev_alloc();
    if(kernel_object == NULL){
       printk(KERN_WARNING "error allocating kernel object\n");
       return -1;
    }
    sdev = (struct scull_dev*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_dev),GFP_KERNEL);
    sdev->cdev = kernel_object;
    sdev->quantum = QUANTUM;
    sdev->qset = Q_SET;
    skull_setup_cdev(sdev);
    allocate_memory(sdev);
    printk("device got registered and inited . ready for connections ... \n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
static void skull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev* c_dev){
    int err;
    cdev_init(c_dev->cdev,&scull_fops);
    c_dev->cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    //c_dev->cdev->ops   = &scull_fops;
    err = cdev_add(c_dev->cdev,dev,NUMBER_DEVICES);
    if(err){
       printk(KERN_WARNING "couldn't add structure to associated major. \n");
    }
}
```

```
static int skull_open(struct inode* inode, struct file* filep){
    struct scull_dev* s_dev;
    printk(KERN_INFO "openend skull device file ... \n");
    s_dev = container_of(&inode->i_cdev,struct scull_dev,cdev);
    printk("%d,%d\n",s_dev->quantum,s_dev->qset);
    filep->private_data = s_dev;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel's `container_of` macro takes a pointer to a structure member, the name of the structure type, and the name of the member, and yields a pointer to the structure.  With that understanding, consider this use:

> ```
>     s_dev = container_of(&inode->i_cdev,struct scull_dev,cdev);
> ```

`inode->i_cdev` is member `i_cdev` of the `struct inode` to which variable `inode` points, so `&inode->i_cdev` is a pointer to a member of a `struct inode`, not to a member of a `struct scull_dev`.  That use of `container_of()` is therefore incorrect.

`inode->i_cdev` is a pointer to a `struct cdev`. If it happens to point to a `struct cdev` that is a member of a `struct scull_dev` then you could use `container_of()`  like so to obtain a pointer to the latter:

```
    s_dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);
```

Note in particular that there the pointer `inode->i_cdev` itself is being passed, not the address of that inode member.

Of course, if the pointed-to `struct cdev` *is not* a member of a `struct scull_dev`, then that will still give you a meaningless result.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. After looking at my code again i found the error ... The problem was me allocating a cdev which gives me just a pointer to the cdev structure. Meaning that my scull_dev structure is just pointing to the cdev pointer and the container_of macro therefore just points to this cdev pointer. I just missread some stuff in the book i'm currently reading :(